# If $q < 0$, prove that the power mean $M_q$ is lesser than the geometric mean $G$

Tags: calculus, inequality, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assuming the lemma that when $p > 0$ then $M_p > G$, I need to prove that if $q < 0$ then $M_q < G$.

I'm trying to prove it this way:

Let $q = -k$ and $k > 0$. Then $(M_k)^k > G^k$ then $(M_{-q})^{-q} > G^{-q}$ then $G^q > (M_{-q})^q$ then $G > M_{-q}$, but now that negative subindex is bothering me and I can't find a way to start with a hypothesis that allows me to conclude that $G > M_{q}$.

I found a solution [here](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/07/10/prove-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-inequality/), in the end of the article, but I don't know how is this implication correct:

> $G^{-q} < (M_{-q})^{-q} \implies G^q > M_{q}^q$

Shouldn't $G^{-q} < (M_{-q})^{-q}$ just imply $G^q > M_{-q}^q$? How can I prove this?

PD: For context, this is the problem 20 of Apostol's Calculus, volume I first chapter, so I would like to keep the proof as basic as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=-q>0$, and apply your lemma to $\frac{1}{x_i}$:
$$\left(\frac{\sum\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{p}}{n}\right)^{\frac 1p} \geqslant \left(\Pi \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{1/n} \implies \left(\frac{\sum\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{-q}}{n}\right)^{\frac {-1}{q}} \geqslant \left(\Pi \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{1/n}\\
\implies \left(\Pi x_i\right)^{1/n} \geqslant \left(\frac{\sum x_i^q}{n}\right)^{\frac {1}{q}}
$$

Comment: Super neat! Thank you :) So the main trick was to use $x_{i}^{-1}$ to cancel later the minus $-q$ exponents.